# javascript variables

Tags: javascript, client-side

Hello just wondering why firbug is stating NaN even when these inputs have information entered.

```
    for(i=1;i<8;i++){
var field = document.ContactForm.Field + i.value;
console.log(field);

    }
```

i am trying to iterate through field1, field2 field3 .... field7.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here, please give a more detailed example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have a number of fields `Field0` ... `Field8`.

For that, you need to use different notation:

```
var field = document.ContactForm[Field + i].value;
```

by the way, while forms can be accessed by name the way you show, a more preferable approach would be the `document.forms` array:

```
 var field = document.forms["ContactForm"]["Field" + i].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `ContactForm.Field` is some Input field so it means it represents and object and so it can't be added with i.value.

So instead you should try

```
var field = document.ContactForm.Field.value + i.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var field = document.getElementById('Field' + i.value).value;
```